# if i want to convert proto to pb.h/pb.cc and add custom function at same file，how can i do

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have read the protobuffer source code, but do not have doc to complete it,I found plugin may work, but do not have idea.

I have read the protobuffer source code, but do not have doc to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear why you would want to do that.

Firstly, the generated .h / .cc are supposed to be untouched, and something you do not modify. If you change them, then you have lost the advantage / purpose of using GPB in the first place, which is that the .proto file is the "one source of truth". If you modify the .h / .cc, the .proto file is now no longer enough.

Secondly, to compile the .cc files, you'll already be compiling several of them and linking against a library. So, it is easy to added your own .cc files to this build process, which is where your custom functions can go. Even in as separate .cc file, they can do everything that you'd ever want them to do (unless you were planning on altering the functions that have been generated from the .proto file).

**Reason to Modify the .cc File Generated from .proto file**

The only reason to modify the .cc files that have been compiled from the .proto file would be to add constraints checking. For example if you had a message:

```
message LimitedInt
{
   // Valid between 0 and 10
   int32 aLimitedInt = 0
}
```

you might want to insert code into the generated .cc file to check that `aLimitedInt` is indeed between 0 and 10. However, this is a very unproductive way of doing it, because if you ever have to change the .proto you'll have to keep re-editing the generated .cc files.

If this is indeed what you want, then there are extensions to GPB that can do this, e.g. [protoc-gen-validate](https://github.com/bufbuild/protoc-gen-validate/blob/main/README.md), though this is described as being alpha quality at the moment. The better answer is to choose something else, like ASN.1 which has constraints as a native and widely implemented part of the standard (though, good ASN.1 tools cost money).

Comment: thx a lot，that's exactly what i want to do.

Comment: message LimitedInt
{
   repeated int32 list = 0;  //@len(msg::MAX_LIST_LEN)
} like this,generate a function to judge the size

Comment: @jefc469, Aha, I thought so! Alas, it's not a very bright situation in GPB with regard to this sort of value / length constraints. The best I've seen is protoc-gen-validate, though as it's Alpha and is incomplete (for C++), then it's hard to recommend it for production-quality projects. If you really need that kind of functionality, ASN.1 really is the best out there, and very similar in concept but older but still modern. In fact, when Google "invented" GPB, somone in the audience at the debut conference asked, "why didn't you just use ASN.1?", which Google hadn't heard of...

Comment: @jefc469 Though, before you rush off and spend money on ASN.1 tools, bear in mind that it's utterly incompatible with GPB. There is a fairly good C implementation that's open source at https://github.com/vlm/asn1c

Comment: haha,thx a lot,I just dont want to touch the source code,the previous versions of the tool did this.

Comment: thx,i will think about it